# Dataset error message - PdwManagedToNativeInteropException

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Currently have a pipeline running in our production environment that has an activity that copies data from an on prem sql database to sql azure database. This pipeline is replicated among the dev and QA environments but don't fail in those environments. Wanted to get a bit more insight as to what this error means.

Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'PdwManagedToNativeInteropException ErrorNumber: 46724,

Comment: "PDW" is short for Parallel Data Warehouse and suggests you might be using the MPP product Azure SQL Data Warehouse, rather than a SQL DB as you mentioned.  Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you! Yes the sink side is data warehouse and not Azure Sql as the original developer had it, switching the sink to SqlDWSink solved the error

Comment: I have upgraded my comment to answer - please mark it correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PDW" is short for Parallel Data Warehouse and suggests you might be using the MPP product Azure SQL Data Warehouse, rather than a SQL DB as you mentioned. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This error reflects when your defined size of the column like varchar /int is getting overflown.

Try increasing the size of data types and column and rerun the pipeline.

I recreated it and fixed it in my Data factory.